# 2D function smooth

Tags: c, 2d

Tengo una señal 2D y quiero crear algun tipo de envolvente. Tiene que ser simétrica entre máximos, por lo que un filtro envolvente no se ajusta a lo que quiero.
Los máximos locales se han de propagar un poco, estoy tratando de simular un tejido y el comportamiento de un hilo una vez tengo las colisiones detectadas.

Estoy realizándolo en C.

Aguna idea?
Gracias

Comment: Hola user. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Aqui se resuelven dudas que han sido trabajadas . Has de mostrar lo intentado y por que no te salió. Si no has empezado has de investigar por tu cuenta. Si en el desarrollo tienes errores o problemas concretos, pregunta aqui. Esta pregunta como está es muy amplia. Para más informacion mira [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Hola! Por qué es muy amplia? Yo creo que es bastante bastante concreta,
estoy preguntando por un filtro que no sé si existe.

Comment: La cosa es que si pides ideas como sugerencias y demás  se considera *basado en opiniones* ya que cada uno puede responderte una cosa y es muy abierto. Si no muestras lo intentado es muy amplia. Te sugiero que investigues por tu cuenta y decidas, entre las opciones descubiertas, como proseguir. si en el proceso tienes dudas concretas como mensajes de error o resultado no esperado, pregunta aqui esa duda en particular mostrando lo que intentaste, los ejemplos para explicar el resultado esperado.. Un saludo

Comment: No estoy del todo de acuerdo, el "alguna idea" era el equivalente a "conocéis algún filtro o porcesado de señal con las características que expongo?" No estoy pidiendo una opinón!
No puedo intentar nada porque no me voy a poner a diseñar un filtro que no sé si existe y reinventar la rueda. Búsquedas en google no me han dado una respuesta, estoy probando multitud de filtros, y preguntaba por eso.

Gracias de todas formas!

Comment: *"Los máximos locales se han de propagar un poco"* ¿Qué es exactamente un poco? ¿Se refiere a los máximos, a los mínimos o a ambos? ¿Y si te encuentras máximos y mínimos en el área de filtrado? ¿Qué área debe cubrir el filtro? ¿Debe ser cuadrado? ¿rectangular quizás? ¿circular? ¿Cómo es la estructura sobre la que trabaja? ¿matriz numérica? ¿datos complejos? Quizás para ti te parece que la pregunta es clara y concisa... pero ya te adelanto yo que para un tercero no lo es